# jQuery from mootool: scrolling animation

Tags: jquery, mootools

http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-css-and-mootools-to-simulate.html

How do I reproduce this in jQuery?

Comment: Umm... Rewrite it? Not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Show me some effort and I'd likely fix and finish it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the excellent [ScrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html). You'll have to put some code of yours to achieve the same exact effect.